# SOAP encoding Problems

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

Hey guys I just started to learn soap and I got a problem when I'm expecting to receive a integer all good and when I'm expecting to receive a string or array or json , error is  :

`SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules`

I already seen all answers about this and it is not helping me. Any ideas what problem is?

Thanks for any advice.

My code is :

```
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
   <definitions name='Names'
             targetNamespace='http://localhost/soap'
             xmlns:tns=' http://localhost/soap '
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
            xmlns:soapenc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'
            xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'
         xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'>

        <message name="getNamesRequest">
            <part name="num" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>
        <message name="getNamesResponse">
            <part name="Result" type="xsd:string"/>
        </message>

        <portType name="NamesPortType">
           <operation name="getNames">
             <input message="tns:getNamesRequest"/>
             <output message="tns:getNamesResponse"/>
           </operation>
        </portType>

        <binding name="NamesBinding" type="tns:NamesPortType">
          <soap:binding style="rpc"
             transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
              <operation name="getNames" />
        </binding>

         <service name="NamesService">
            <port name="NamesPort" binding="tns:NamesBinding" >
             <soap:address
                location="http://localhost/soap/server.php" />
             </port>
         </service>
    </definitions>
```

*server.php*

```
     <?php

       function getNames($num)
        {

          $name = $num;
          return $name;
         }

       ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0');

         $server = new SoapServer("http://localhost/soap/names.wsdl");

          $server->addFunction("getNames");

           $server->handle();
```

*client.php*

```
          <?php

              try {
                 $client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/soap/names.wsdl');
                 $result = $client->getNames('victor');

                 echo $result;
              } catch (SoapFault $e) {
                  echo $e->getMessage();
              }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please initialize your server and client with `UTF-8` encoding:

```
$server = new SoapServer('http://localhost/soap/names.wsdl', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/soap/names.wsdl', array('encoding'=>'UTF-8'));
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but did you restart your web server after changing it?

Comment: yes i did and that is not helping me... can't understand where is the broblem (

Comment: Can you try passing `"trace" => 1` as a parameter to the client? then print the response using `$client->__getLastResponse()` after calling `getNames` and see what you get as a response?

Comment: i have my string in response . this is what i got in response `string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:getNamesResponse><Result>victor</Result></SOAP-ENV:getNamesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
'`

Comment: Are you using `PHP 5.2.6` ?